# How do I tell which package manager I used to install a program?

Tags: package-management

I use a lot of different package managers to install various pieces of software on my PC: `apt`, `apt-get`, `pip`, `snap`, basically whatever the online documentation recommends. How do I tell which package manager I used to install a specific program? I'd like to update it using the same method.

Comment: Suggestion: When you use some online guide to install random software, keep notes on what you installed, when, why, and a link to those instructions. Someday you will need to retrace your steps for maintenance, troubleshooting, or rebuilding.

Comment: Aside: `apt` and `apt-get` are the two different front ends for the same package management system - i.e. you can use them interchangeably for managing the same package.

Comment: Your intuition is good. This is *precisely the reason* that you should only ever use one package manager. Unfortunately, people often only package software for their "favourite" package manager, and everyone else is stuck until a port is written. I encourage you to write those ports!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could try the following to give you clues on which package manager was used:

`snap list`

`pip list`

`apt list --installed`

In the case of `apt` or `apt-get`, the list may be very long, so you could use grep to filter the results. eg. `apt list --installed | grep firefox`

Comment: The "quiet" option can be used with apt like so `apt -qq list --installed firefox` to print only the specified package name if it is installed.

Comment: Also, please keep in mind that `pip list` may give different outputs depending on the version of python that is currently "active" (first in `$PATH`). Even a vanilla Ubuntu (without any virtualenvs or additional python versions) will have at least 2 python versions (v2 and v3) installed.

Answer (score -3):

Lazy method: Search your shell history for the line that actually installed the package.

Comment: Very unlikely to work unless you entered less than 500 commands since the install (standard cutoff for `.bash_history`; details may vary depending on shell and config)

Comment: /etc/skel/.bashrc:HISTSIZE=1000 - not much better though.